# php function to get n number of parameters in single array

Tags: php, arrays, parameters

I am new to php and not familiar with it ,I want to create a function that accepts n parameters as a single array. for example

```
function select(user,pass,salt,... n)
```

in above function the parameters passed should be got in a single array as like below

```
{
$select; \\this variable gets all those passed parameters as a single array 
}
```

Comment: [`func_get_args`](http://php.net/func_get_args), then [`array_slice`](http://php.net/array_slice) out what you want. Or use [variadic functions on 5.6+](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/variadics).

Answer (score 0):

You can give whole array as a function parameter, see my example below.

```
// define parameters for function 
$params = array(
    'user' => 'admin', 
    'pass' => 'abcd', 
    'n' => 'nth_param'
); // salt 'param' isn't defined

// define function 'select'   
function select ($params) {
    $user = isset($params['user']) ? $params['user'] : NULL;
    $salt = isset($params['salt']) ? $params['salt'] : NULL; // you can set default value instead of NULL here
    // ...

    return '...';
}

// function call
select ($params);
```

Comment: i am not passing a array(i don't want to pass a array as parameters), i am passing n values to a function the values passed should be caught into a array @panther

Answer (score 0):

Use the func_get_args function to get all arguments passed to a function and store in an array.

```
<?php

function select("user","pass","salt",... n)
{

$arg_list = func_get_args();
print $arg_list[0];

}

//this will output "user"

?>
```

Comment: i am not passing a array, i am passing n values to a function the values passed should be caught into a array @the_big_blackbox